# Outlook 2010 with Exchange Online - Which version of TLS is being used?

Tags: exchange, outlook

How do I check which version of TLS is being used in Outlook 2010 with Office 365 Exchange Online mail server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be TLS 1.2, because as of October 31, 2018, Office 365 will no longer support TLS 1.0 and 1.1. 
Preparing to use TLS 1.2 in Office 365
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4057306/preparing-for-tls-1-2-in-office-365

You could use Network Monitor to check which version of TLS is being used in Outlook 2010 with Office 365.
https://www.lee-ford.co.uk/psa-tls1-2-ticking-timebomb/

Comment: Is there a easier way to find the TLS version being used instead of using Network Monitor?

Comment: Maybe there is other smilar softwares, but i didnt know.